# What exactly is a forward declaration with respect to memory?

Tags: c++, c, memory-model

I understand on a high level what a function declaration does: you declare them at the top of your file so the compiler will know which functions you are calling. However, what does the compiler exactly do with it? I know that functions are written in the text section of memory and expects arguments to be given by a register on the stack. Are function prototypes also placed within the text? Or are forward declarations simply indicators for the linkage editor to use to connect all the files together, and they are "removed" in the final product? Or does the compiler do something else with them?

I have looked around online and could not find a good resource, so if any of you can answer this or give me a resource outlining this specific phenomena, that would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I think there was a misunderstanding in the question, which is my mistake. My question was on how exactly does the C-compiler utilize the forward declarations. It seems from the answers below, it is used during the conversion of c-code to assembly. Is this correct?

Comment: I think you mean to say `forward declaration` instead of `function prototype`. am I correct?

Comment: Function prototypes are used by the compiler for error checking and automatic type conversions. They aren't put into the object file, and aren't used by the linker.

Comment: You can read this [similar question](/questions/4055391/whats-the-point-of-function-prototyping)

Comment: @SouravGhosh i believe you are correct, that it should be forward declaration. It seems that function prototype has become synonymous with forward declaration in a bunch of tutorials online, when in reality they are two seperate things. I will update the question

Comment: @user3386109 so the forward declarations are only utilized in error checking process of the c compilation?

Comment: @user3855005 so, forward declarations is a way to let the compilar know the function signature to use when the function is called/used before its is defined.

Comment: @SSC I read the question and one of the answers stated that the compiler builds a table of these function to prevent a second pass. so during the conversion of c code into assembly, the compiler just constructs this table and converts the code in this way?

Comment: @user3855005 I am not expert regarding the question you ask.  I just thought the linked question may be some help to you.  Maybe others will clarify that for you.  Sorry.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I understand that, but how exactly does the compiler do it? Does it build a table of functions with its identifiers during the conversion from c to assembly, as previously suggested? And after this phase they are no longer used?

Answer (score 8):

A function prototype is simply a way to notify the compiler about *how* the function should be called, without having to provide any details on the implementation.

All a caller needs to know is how to call it: what parameters to pass and what to expect back.

Everything else should be hidden as much as possible so as to allow proper encapsulation, the ability for a function to change however it wants internally, without breaking anyone currently using it.

By way of example, here's a function prototype used for storing key-value pairs (both strings):

```
enum kvpErr kvpAdd (char *key, char *value);
```

This allows the compiler to ensure that you actually pass *in* two C strings and take an integral error code back. But it reveals *nothing* about the internals of the function. It may use various forms of balanced trees, a dynamically allocated array, a connection to an SQL database or a text file on an NFS server located in Outer Mongolia.

The bottom line is, you can improve the *implementation* in any way you wish as long as the *function signature itself* is kept identical.